# Debugging a vstemplate wizard

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-templates

For a game engine called duality (https://duality.adamslair.net/) I want to make a solution template that will create the necessary projects and all the files needed for duality to function. This includes files and folders that are not part of a project themselves.

In order to achieve this iam trying to make a wizard that can generate the files/folder structure I need as I understood that templates alone are quite limited in this aspect. I followed this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx.

However when I debug this and try to create the solution it says it failed but not why or how. Breakpoints are not being hit either since the symbols are not loaded.

This is the error I get when trying to create a project using my template: [image]

When I comment out the WizardExtension node in the vstemplate it works fine

So how do I change my project so that it does load the symbols and I can debug it? Iam using vs2017.

Included is my project: 
[DualityTemplate](https://github.com/AdamsLair/duality/files/1394398/DualityTemplate.zip)

Comment: Start VS again and use Debug > Attach to Process to attach it to the first instance.  Set breakpoints, they'll run from hollow to solid as soon as the first instance loads the wizard code.  Exercise the wizard in the first instance.

Comment: Its not working. When debug the vs instance and create a project using my template it just says 'project creation failed' and nothing else happens. No breakpoint being hit just nothing. Frustrating how something that should be so simple has been made so complicated by ms.

Comment: Verify that the breakpoints were armed and are now solid.  Debug > Break All in the second instance, then Debug > Windows > Modules.  Find your wizard assembly back in the list and verify that it has the PDB file loaded.  Right-click > Symbol Load Information if it didn't.

Comment: I can not find my wizard module and breakpoints are not armed

Comment: I also see a BadImageFormatException in the output so guessing something is going wrong when it tries to load the dll. I don't know what though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because the platform was set to Any Cpu. When I changed this to x86 it worked without problems.

This is most likely cause by the extension deciding to run in 64 bit while visual studio is only 32 bit.